# Deny countries exclude specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, block

i block users from specifics countries by this:

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
order allow,deny
deny from 193.34.36.0/22
deny from 193.58.216.0/21
deny from 193.164.220.0/23
deny from 194.42.216.0/24
deny from 195.42.132.0/23
deny from 195.66.102.0/24
deny from 195.66.132.0/23
deny from 195.190.24.0/24
deny from 195.200.84.0/23
deny from 195.216.225.0/24
.......
allow from all
</Limit>

<FilesMatch "blockPage\.php|main\.css|logo\.png">
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 403 /blockPage.php
```

this code redirect to page "blockPage.php" where you are user from this countries.

in this htaccess i have a redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule ^points/?$  main.php?mode=points [QSA,L]
```

i want that all the countries block not deny pages in "points" directory
(points is not a real directory its only htaccess redirect)
actually when mode=points dont deny user.

tnx a lot

Comment: `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/points/?$#"><Limit> ... </Limit></If>` with new lines after each tag.

Comment: it may also catch the main.php, so in this case try the `<If "%{THE_REQUEST} !~ m#\s/points/?\s#">`

Comment: @Deadooshka tnx for your help, actually its not run the line:
"ErrorDocument 403 /blockPage.php"